# Rounding a number

Tags: c#, rounding

```
var output = Convert.ToDecimal(amount / 4);

labelOutput.Text = "You need: " + System.Math.Round(output,0);
```

this code is part of a calculator for a game

"amount" is how much the user wants to make, and to make a single item, you need 4 pieces ( / 4)

for instance:

*how much?: 20*

*20 / 4 = 5*

*"you need 5 pieces*

but when i enter 21, still says 5 pieces but the users needs 6 pieces to make 21 items (4 for every item)

**How can i round up the output to make it say 6 instead of 5 when the input is, in this case, 21 - 23?**

(sorry if I didn't explain it good enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var output = Math.Ceiling(amount / 4);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `Math.Ceiling`

Comment: `Math.Ceiling` only works if the result from the division includes the remainder

Answer (score 3):

To give a complete answer (combining the above):

- Problem 1: You're doing [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)
- Problem 2: You need to use [`Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling) instead of [`Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round)

Assuming that `amount` is an integer, you need to have one of the values in your division operation be non-integral (either `float`/`double` or `decimal`, I've opted for `decimal` in my example with the `m` suffix).  If both parts of the division operation are integral types, you'll get an integral answer (dropping the remainder).

You then call `Ceiling` to get the smallest integer value equal to or greater than `output` (rather than `Round`, which gives the closest integer value to `output`).

```
var output = amount / 4m;
labelOutput.Text = "You need: " + System.Math.Ceiling(output);
```

Comment: Normally I'd be a little concerned about some sort of weird rounding error causing a value like 5.0 being internally equal to 5.00000003212 or whatever, which might break on this code.  Since the number he is dividing by is a power of 2, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The round function rounds the number to the nearest one.

For a round up you have to use [Math.Ceiling()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx)
If you need to round down you have to use [Math.Floor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx)

Comment: when i put in <code>System.Math.Ceiling(output);</code> it still doenst work, anything between whole numbers should be rounded up to a whole number(5,00000001 should be 6)

Comment: Does not work with what error? Math.Ceiling needs a double as an argument. Try Math.Ceiling((double)output);

Comment: You can also use integer casting to drop the decimal portion I believe, in the case that you may have needed to use Floor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'amount' is an integer type, then the problem here is that you are a performing an integer (whole-number) division right in your first line.

Try changing the first line to: `var output = Convert.ToDecimal(amount) / 4.0;`

Answer (score 0):

`Round` will round the number off -- what you want is to always round up, which you can get by using the `Ceiling` function

Comment: Thanks guys! it works now, and i use this <code>labelOutput.Text = "You need: " + System.Math.Ceiling((double)output);</code> How can i mark this question as answered?

Comment: @klopske You should be able to hover over the hollow tick to the left, and click on that...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.Ceiling(amount / 4)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly, perhaps: `var output = Convert.ToDecimal((amount+3) / 4);` There's an edge case if your amount is right next to MaxValue where this code could break, depending on your denominator.